# Accessing TFS endpoint programmatically

Tags: tfs, automation, autologin

I am trying to access a TFS endpoint using the following code:

```
Uri collectionUri = new Uri("https://tfsendpoint.com:8443");
NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(<username>, <password>);
WindowsCredential windowsCredential = new WindowsCredential(networkCredential);
TfsClientCredentials tfsClientCredentials = new TfsClientCredentials(windowsCredential);
tfsClientCredentials.AllowInteractive = false;
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri, tfsClientCredentials);
tpc.Authenticate();
WorkItemStore workItemStore = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

But the tpc.Authenticate() is throwing a 403 Forbidden error. When I access the same endpoint(https://tfsendpoint.com:8443) through a browser, it is popping up a UI window to enter a username and password. Once entered, it is logging in and allowing access to the TFS items.

Wondering what changes are needed in the code to allow the programmatic login to go through. I tried BasicAuthCredential, SimpleWebTokenCredential. But getting the same 403 Forbidden result.

Comment: Your code seems good. How about you set tfsClientCredentials.AllowInteractive to true to have a prompt UI to let user insert username and password?

Comment: I tried this. But it didn't work either. Please see my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Change the collection URL to this format:

```
Uri collectionUri = new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/collectionname");
```

Comment: Getting an error TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/collectionname.

Comment: in your case it will be: http://{changetoTFSServerName}:8443/{changetoTFSCollectionName}

Comment: Have you tried steps: https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2010/03/15/cannot-access-tfs-over-https-after-upgrade-from-2010-beta-2-to-rc.aspx

Comment: I did try the above code locally on my TFS instance (not SSL enabled) and it worked fine.

Comment: There seems to be something going on the network. The same code with the same username and password credentials is working on one system, but not working on another system. So there is nothing wrong with code as some have pointed out. 

I contacted the server admins and working with them to resolve the issue. I will post if I can find something useful.